# Refresh screen when modifying from api using react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am creating an application to order food online and I want to perform a functionality where the user does not have to scroll or do any action to see reflected on the screen of their device that their order has changed status.

Example: The user enters to see the status of their order and being there on that screen that the user can see how the status of the order is updated without having to scroll.

I don't know if I should use listeners or some way with async and wait

I am using react native with hooks, react navigation 5, axios for API call

Do you know how I could do this? how can I find more information on this.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can solve this.

1. Polling - you can create some interval, say 1 second, for axios to refetch the data you need. Wrapping your axios call with setInterval() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp, is one form of this.
2. Web Sockets - you can create a web socket that maintains a constant connection to your app and server, so when updates happen it is automatically reflected in the UI. You can check out WebSocket support in React Native here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/network.html#websocket-support

Comment: Thank you very much, I have also found that it can be used with pusher or fire base. I will read your recommendations.